# edit_content_path wrong Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi!

I have many links like <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_content_path(content) %> but since my Rails update and some other route changes the path is wrong.

It leads to domain/contents instead of the correct domain/subfolder/contents... what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Run $ rake routes. I am unable to give you any feedback based just on the route file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you nested any routes in your routes.rb file?

If you you will have to add the parent to the path.

```
edit_parent_content_path(@parent, @content_id)
```

Something like that. Running ->

```
$ rake routes
```

Will help you determine if it is a route problem. (Try to find your current path in the results.)

If you still have a problem, post your routes.rb file.

Comment: I changed to: map.connect 'subfolder/:controller/:action/:id. I will post the routes.rb file when I come home, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my routes.rb:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  map.root :controller => "store"

  map.resources :users
  map.resources :orders, :controller => 'order'
  map.resources :contents
  map.resources :products

  map.resources :kundservice => "store/kundservice"
  map.resources :foretaget => "store/foretaget"

  # Install the default routes as the lowest priority.
  map.connect 'subfolder/:controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect 'subfolder/:controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Because of the hostcompany where I have my site, I must have it in a subfolder  under my domain, www.domain.com/subfolder/store.

Thanks!

Comment: Edit you post with this info.